# SPSS: Multiple data lines for individual cases

Tags: spss

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID Time  Date_____v1 v2 v3 v4   
1 2300 21/01/2002 1 996 5 300

1 0200 22/01/2002    3             1000     6          100

1 0400 22/01/2002    5             930      3          100

1 0700 22/01/2002    1             945      4          200
```

I have 50+ cases and 15+ variables in both categorical and measurement form (although SPSS will not allow me to set it as Ordinal and Scale I only have the options of Nominal and Ordinal?).

I am looking for trends and cannot find a way to get SPSS to recognise each case as whole rather than individual rows. I have used a pivot table in excel which gives me the means for each variable but I am aware that this can skew the result as it removes extreme readings (I need these ideally).

I have searched this query online multiple times but I have come up blank so far, any suggestions would be gratefully received!

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. Maybe you can better explain what you are trying to do + add a sample of the desired data structure. In any case look up `casestovars` command - that would be my first guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. If you are saying that each case has multiple records (that is multiple lines of data) - which is what it looks like in your example - then either

1) Your `DATA LIST` command needs to change to add RECORDS= (see the Help for the DATA LIST command); or

2) You will have to use CASESTOVARS (C2V) to put all the variables for a case in the same row of the Data Editor.

I may not be understanding, though.